# instance variable not modified in a for loop

Tags: python, class, for-loop, instance-variables

I have a class with instance variables which I want to modify in a loop using a class method, simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,x,z):
        self.x=x
        self.z=z

    def run(self,y):

        temp_list=[self.x, self.z]

        for ind,item in enumerate(temp_list):
            temp_list[ind] = temp_list[ind]+y

        print (self.x, self.z)

ex = Example(5,6)
ex.run(5)
```

The output I get is [5,6] instead of the desired [10,11].
I was wondering if anyone could point me to an explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: Fundamentally, your misunderstanding *what you are modifying*. You modify the list, not the objects in the list. It is worth reading Ned Batchelder's [Facst and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Note also, this has nothing to do with instance variables. You would see the same behavior if you did `x = 5; y =6; temp_list = [x, y]`and then did the same loop.

Comment: Thank you again for explaining this, and thank you for the link, will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 5):

In `run()`, you create a list of 2 items, the value `self.x` and `self.z`. Next, you iterate over that list, and modify each value by adding `y` to it.
After the `for`-loop, `temp_list` will be `[10, 11]`, but you have not modified `self.x` or `self.y` in any way.

Hence, the `print()` call will print the unmodified `self.x` and `self.y` values, being 5 and 6 in your example.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise making a list creates a copy of the variables... Is it possible to actually then somehow modify the instance variables in a for-loop?

Comment: Not easily, no.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could move `x` and `z` to a list right away in your `__init__()` function: `self.x_and_z = [x, z]`. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46201154/3486486)

Comment: @Ale **no** making a `list` **does not create a copy of the variables**. The issue is that you are *modifying the list*, you are *not modifying the objects in the list*.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't actually write `self.x = ...`, then you can generally assume that `self.x` will not be modified. When you write `temp_list[ind] + y` and store it in `temp_list[ind]`, you're updating *the list* with a new value, which has no bearing on any values that other variables happen to hold (including your object's `x` variable).

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference now, thank you both for explaining this!

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result with code similar to yours, you could do something like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,x,z):
        self.list=[x, z]
    def run(self,y):

        for ind,item in enumerate(self.list):
            self.list[ind] = self.list[ind]+y

        print (self.list)

ex = Example(5,6)
ex.run(5)
```

This would create a `self.list` item in your init definition that would then be used to iterate over the initial values and add your `y` value to it. The main error you had was printing an unaltered list (but you were on the right track!)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use, the example under.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, x, z):
        self.x = x
        self.z = z

    def run(self,y):
        # Put your init arguments into the array
        result = [self.x, self.z]

        # Modify your init arguments
        for x in range(len(result)):
            result[x] += y

        # Return the array with new values
        return result

ex = Example(5, 6)
print(ex.run(5))
```

Maybe the link would be helpful for you, [learn for loop in python](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops)